# Error : No operator “<<” matches these operands

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I'm still fairly rusty at c++ and I'm having trouble understanding my issue. The error message that I am receiving is "No operator '<<' matches these operands" The code I have:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ruleList.size(); i++)
{
    cout << ruleList[i].lhs << endl;
    cout << ruleList[i].rhs << endl; // Problem printing this
}
```

---

```
struct Rules
{
string lhs;
vector<string> rhs;
}rule;
```

---

```
vector<Rules> ruleList;
```

---

Would this be the appropriate way to do this? I did the lhs the same way and it works fine.

```
rule.rhs.push_back(token);
ruleList.push_back(rule);
```

Comment: A `vector` cannot be printed directly using `cout`. Loop over the vector and print each element one by one,

Answer (score 2):

There is no `operator<<` defined for standard containers. You will need to write a print function, something along the lines of:

```
void print(std::ostream& out, std::vector<std::string> const & data) {
   std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(),
             std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(out, " "));
}
```

And then use it as:

```
print(std::cout, ruleList[i].rhs);
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` does not define an `operator <<`. You can use a `std::ostream_iterator` to format a list:

```
std::copy( ruleList[i].rhs.begin(), ruleList[i].rhs.end(),
           std::ostream_iterator< std::string >( std::cout, ", " ) );
```

This is a bit imperfect in that `", "` is printed after the final element, but that can be worked around.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own `<<` operator for `struct rules`. It should look something like this in C++11:

```
struct rules {
    string lhs;
    std::vector<std::string> rhs;

    // apparently it's a good idea to keep this out of std:: namespace
    inline static std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & out, const rules & r) {
        out << r.lhs << std::endl;
        //for (int i = 0; i < v.length(); i++)
        for (auto & s : r.rhs) {
            out << s;
        }
        out << std::endl;
        return out;
    }
}
```

MSDN has a write up here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx

Comment: **Don't**, you cannot properly overload the operator outside of `::std` (ADL won't find it), and you cannot legally provide the overload inside of `::std`.

Comment: Based on the wikipedia article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) I don't think this is a problem unless you're working on a huge codebase will a lot of conflicting overloads. **But** precisely the same argument could be made for **any** function in C++.

Comment: The problem is that the particular function is a *common* one. It is *very* frequent to find `operator<<` in whatever namespace your code lives in, and in that case unqualified lookup won't look in the outer namespace and will fail. Where does it differ from other functions? When was the last time you saw an operator call being qualified? `::operator<<(std::cout, myvector)`? Considering that in the general case you don't even know whether that or `std::cout.operator<<(object)` would be the right syntax... operators are **the** reason for ADL.

Comment: Considering that in his case `operator <<` isn't working already that means that `operator <<` *isn't* already defined so it should be ok for him to do it in this case without worrying about a name clash/shadow. I'm still not convinced that it's Bad Practice to override things in general, but thank you for pointing out some problems that could occur.

Comment: You are not understanding my point. Overloading operators is good, but it has to be in the **right** namespace. Except that the *right* namespace cannot be used here as you cannot add overloads to the `::std` namespace. The problem is not overloading *operator<<*, but doing so in the **wrong** namespace (given that the *right* one would be illegal). In what namespace would you define this? Global? Now consider that you have a type `::A::T` which also has `::A::operator<<(std::ostream&,::A::T const&)`, now consider a function nested inside `::A` […]

Comment: […] say `::A::f()` and that internally you have a `std::vector<std::string>` named `v`, that you want to print. Would `std::cout << v;` work? **No**.

Comment: -1, this is incompatible with maintainable coding practices. Just because it appears in a Wikipedia article doesn't make it a good idea.